# How do I change the Keychaing password on a used Apple Mac

Tags: macos, password, keychain

I bought a used Apple all in one Desktop Computer. I need to know how to change the Keychain password since I don't know it. The man passed away and I purchased it at an auction.

Is there anything else that I should do since it's used to update the info on the computer. I was able to change the login password.

Comment: You need to boot into recovery mode, format the drive in disk utility, and reinstall. Hopefully the previous owner didn't set a bootloader password...

Comment: @Wowfunhappy great answer, however be cautious providing information how to crack or recover passwords without understanding or verifying it is the rightful owner. We get many questions like that.

Comment: @Buscar웃 This will not bypass anything. It simply erases/reformats the drive and reinstalls macOS. You will end up with a clean computer free of stuff from the previous owner.

Comment: @JBis  I know that. It will be with or without owners consent. Wait, this one died.

Comment: @Buscar웃 Lets find out XD  Hi Wendy R. Did you steal this computer?

Comment: @Buscar웃 You actually bring up a good point. Maybe ask on Meta.  If someone asks a good question but with unethical intentions, how should we handle.

Comment: @Buscar웃 Taken at face value, there is nothing unethical about this question. A deceased person's possessions were being auctioned off, and OP bought a password protected computer. I find that to be a very plausible scenario. Yes, OP *could* be lying, but I'm not inclined to *assume* they're lying. And I didn't advise them to break encryption or anything, just format the computer.

Comment: @Wowfunhappy when you go to Apple with bricked device, they will ask you to prove to be the rightful owner. When you loose password to any website, they will send you verification email on they records. A story is a story. And the auction ppl would have to disclose that it is locked.